# Count the length of a chain in SQL

Tags: sql, sas, chain

I have a table in SAS/SQL such as the following:

**Input**

```
Field1  Field2
A       B
E       F
C       D
B       C
```

I want to have a third column that tells me the length of the "chains" that can be made with Field1 and Field2. I will explain with an example. In our case, I'd want:

**Output**

```
Field1 Field2 Length
A      B      1
B      C      2
C      D      3
E      F      1
```

What this would do is find "chains" and compute its length. In the example we would have 2 chains: "A-B-C-D" and "E-F". The chain is formed first taking a row with a beginning of a chain, in this case "A-B". Then, because the value in Field2 is B it would look for the value B in Field1 and write it under the first row with the new corresponding value of Field2, in this case "B-C". Then it would check if the value C exists in Field1, and if that's the case write it down. In our case it would be "C-D". Again, it would check if value D exists in Field1. Because it does not exist it would begin the algorithm with the following chain, and would write "E-F" which does not have more connections.

The length value would give how "deep" that pair is. "A-B" is the first pair, "B-C" is the second pair of the chain "A-B-C" and "C-D" is the third pair of the chain "A-B-C-D".

I can't come with a solution, any help to achieve this?. It does not need to be exactly in this form, any workarounds would be of big help also.

If it matters, for a given row it's never the case that Field1 = Field2.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need recursive CTEs. SAS doesn't have these yet, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in the SQL implementation in SAS.

Lots of ways to do this in the data step.  The hash object is probably the easiest if you understand hashes.  Use a hash iterator to grab the first row from the hash, then grab any row that matches the field2; if no row matches the field2, stop looking and let the iterator pull the next one out.

```
data have;
input Field1 $ Field2  $;
datalines;
A       B
E       F
C       D
B       C
;;;;
run;

data want;
  if 0 then set have;
  declare hash h(dataset:'have', ordered:'a');
  h.defineKey('field1');
  h.defineData('field1','field2');
  h.defineDone();
  declare hiter hi('h');

  do rc = hi.next() by 0 while (rc=0);  *outside iterator - grab the next available row;
    seq = 1;        *initialize the sequence variable;
    output;         *output the first row;
    do rc_h = h.find(key:field2) by 0 while (rc_h=0);  *inside seek - looks for a row (anywhere) that matches field2.;
      seq=seq+1;    *increment the sequence variable;
      output;       *output this row;
      rc_r = h.remove();          *remove that row from the hash as it has been "used";
      rc_h = h.find(key:field2);  *look to see if there is another match in this sequence;
    end;
    rc = hi.next();
  end;
  stop;
  drop rc:;
run;
```